# jQuery hide/show divs on radio select and/or page load

Tags: jquery

Here is my HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="search_criteria" value="division" <?php if($_SESSION['search_by'] == 'division') { echo "checked"; } ?>>
<div class="hide_div" id="show_division" style="display: none;">
    ...Some Code...
</div>
```

I'm using the following script to show/hide DIV's if certain radio buttons are selected.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var demovalue = $(this).val(); 
        $("div.hide_div").hide();
        $("#show_"+demovalue).show();
    });
});
```

This works as expected.

While processing my form using PHP, if errors are found, the user is sent back to the form and the radio button they originally selected is auto selected again.  How can I show the div associated with the radio button on page load?

I've tried this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        var demovalue = $(this).val(); 
        $("div.hide_div").hide();
        $("#show_"+demovalue).show();
    });
    $('input[type="radio"]').is(":checked") {
        var demovalue = $(this).val(); 
        $("#show_"+demovalue).show();
    });
});
```

When I load the page, the correct radio button is marked as CHECKED, but the associated DIV does not show.

Any ideas where I may have gone wrong?

Comment: the same condition you use to "check" the radio button can be used to show the div with "display:none" or "display:block" as needed, instead of using php in one and javascript in another.

Comment: So, you think something like this:  <?php if($_SESSION['search_by'] == 'division') { echo "style=\"display: block;\""; } else { echo "style=\"display: hidden;\""; } ?>

Comment: exactly, or `<div class="hide_div" id="show_division" style="display:<?php echo ($_SESSION['search_by'] == 'division'? 'block':'hidden');?>">
    ...Some Code...
</div>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the associated `div`s on client side, you have to iterate over all your checked checkboxes. You can do so with the help of the [checked](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector and the *[each](https://api.jquery.com/each/#each-function)* method.

The result should look something like this:

```
$('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function() {
    var demovalue = $(this).val(); 
    $("#show_"+demovalue).show();
});
```